# Is my guppy pregnant? If so what should I do?

Tags: aquarium, fish, breeding, guppies

It is not a clear picture but you can see her on the right side of the picture, we bought her 3-4 days ago and I noticed that she was a little fatter than other female fish.

Is my guppy pregnant?

Do I need to keep her separated from other fish?

What should I do?

[image]